# How to generate a 64 bit COM Proxy

Tags: c++, com, proxy, atl, atlcom

I have a 32 bit COM server (and the source code for it)
The source generates the server and a 32 bit proxy stub. (The MIDL compiler generates the proxy stub code.)

I would like to make a 64 bit proxy as well, so that 64 bit programs can talk to my 32 bit COM server.

How do I go about converting a 32 bit proxy into a 64 bit proxy that talks to a 32 bit process?
I'm guessing that just recompiling with /D:_M_AMD64 is not enough.

Comment: No, /D isn't enough, you actually have to use a 64-bit compiler.  Add the x64 platform configuration for the PS project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proxy code generated by the MIDL compiler should work.  You just need to build a 64-bit dll from that code.

Make sure your types are defined properly.  Make sure you avoid types like UINT_PTR which will not work when a 64-bit caller calls a 32-bit server.